# Check if a string is of form 0^n 1^n

Tags: bison, yacc

I have a Yacc program to check if a number is of the form 0^n 1^n.

```
%start S
%%
    S:'0' S '1' {printf("Success\n");}|;
%%
```

(All tokens are defined in a lex file)

The output I get is as follows

```
0011
Success
Success
syntax error

1100
syntax error
```

I understand why Success is printed twice,but what is the syntax error doing in the 1st output?

Further, how does `bison`, a LALR(1) parser generator do this task?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error comes from the fact that your grammar does not recognize the empty string, so once all of the `'1' S '0'` productions have been reduced, no progress can be made.

Bison refuses to accept that grammar, but it's easy to fix:

```
%start S
%%
S: '1' S '0'
 | ;
%%
```

Just looking at the grammar, it should be clear how to parse the string with one-token lookahead. In fact, the grammar is LL(1); you simply need a stack (or counter) of the `1`s encountered. If that's not a sufficient explanation, enable bison's tracing feature and watch the parse happen.

Comment: @PaulDaviesC: what code? and who are you with respect to this question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your grammar only matches infinite strings -- there are no finite strings in the language described by your grammar.

You need to add a 'base case' with a finite string, so it can accept that string or strings built up from it.  The obvious case being the empty string (for n = 0):

```
S : /* empty */
  | '0' S '1'
  ;
```

Comment: my grammar will accept empty strings.please see the above code.